# Link DropDown Bootstrap wont work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a link in my NAV to produce a dropdown menu (class="dropdown-menu") when hovering or clicking it.

The following code doesn't produce a dropdown menu when clicked or hovered upon.  I made sure the bootstrap CDN is loading properly.

What is wrong with the following code?

```
<li><a href="createTeam.php"><img width='20' src='./icons/pencil.png'>הקמת צוות שיפור</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b class="caret"></b>דוחות</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                        </ul>   
                    </li>
```

Comment: This is first of all no question, second you did not provide any useful code, if you don't want downvotes to hail down on you, [follow these rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please use this code for Bootstrap Dropdown

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
                                           
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, but my issue is with a link not a button.

Comment: Plus, i tried a button - doesnt work either.

Comment: Hi @JonDror Please provide some more code to check the same...